# How to quickly copy 750Gb of data from 1Tb Elements external hard drive to 2Tb external hard drive

Tags: external-hdd, rsync, cp

Please to explain me step-by-step with an example or screenshots. 
I tried copying the data using rsync and cp but I failed and the data was copied too slowly.

Comment: Western Digital Elements external hard drives come with backup software for Windows pre-installed on the hard drive that writes your backed-up data incrementally all over the drive in a way that is opaque to non-Windows operating systems. If you have used this miserable program to backup your files on the WD Elements external HDD, you can either grind it out manually one file at a time or else copy the data while running Windows.

Comment: Install Grsync, a graphical user interface for Rsync, it's very easy to use and available in the software center as well.

Comment: "the data was copied too slowly"  that's your opinion. You don't even give is the average speed so how can we confirm this? I can tell you 750Gb is not going to be copied in a few minutes when over USB...

Answer (score 0):

I assume these are USB drives.  If this is the case then you are bound to slow copy speeds.  Disk speeds, file size, file count, file path length all play into copy speeds. CIFS data is usually slower to copy than NFS data.  There are a lot of factors involved.  If this is CIFS data then try RichCopy multithreaded.  If this is NFS data then stick with rsync.